# React wait for data to fetch from api and then send to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetch the data from an API with covid-19 cases and store that in a react hook then i try to send the data to a child component but i got error because data is undefined the problem is how code execute he dont have time to take the data from the api and directly send to the child but idk how to fix if someone can help i will appreciate that. Here is th code:

````
//importing components
import Main from './components/Main/Main'
import Second from './components/Second/Second'
//import style
import './App.scss'



// api for testing => https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState() //here we get the data from the API
  const [drop, setDrop] = useState(null)


  const getValue = (e) => {
    setDrop(e.target.value)

  }


  useEffect(() => {
    let URL;

    if (drop === null) {
      URL = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'
    } else {
      URL = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${drop}?strict=true`
    }


    //getting data from the api
    fetch(URL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setData(data))

  })



  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="first">
        <Main info={data} getValue={getValue} />
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(drop) }}>testing</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data) }}>testing API</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data.deaths) }}>testing deaths</button>
      </div>
      <div className="bla">
        <Second />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App```
````

Comment: `{data &&  <Main data={data} getValue={getValue} />}`

Comment: Add `if (!data) return null;` before your `return` stmt. And also add dependencies of data and drop to your `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: `data !== undefined &&`

```
return data !== undefined && (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="first">
        <Main info={data} getValue={getValue} />
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(drop) }}>testing</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data) }}>testing API</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data.deaths) }}>testing deaths</button>
      </div>
      <div className="bla">
        <Second />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

edit:

```
return data !== undefined ? (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="first">
        <Main info={data} getValue={getValue} />
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(drop) }}>testing</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data) }}>testing API</button>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log(data.deaths) }}>testing deaths</button>
      </div>
      <div className="bla">
        <Second />
      </div>
    </div>
  ): (
 <div className="wrapper">
    Loading...
    </div>
)
```

Comment: i have also edited the answer if that could also help

Comment: ow is the same logic like if data is not equal with undefined then return that block of code and like this the code will take that much time to get the res from API i am right?

Comment: yes , it depends how much time you server api is taking in getting the response, in this case you can show <div> loading...</div> like i have added in the edited code

Answer (score 1):

```
 return (
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="first">
    {data!==undefined &&<Main info={data} getValue={getValue} />}
    <button onClick={() => { console.log(drop) }}>testing</button>
    <button onClick={() => { console.log(data) }}>testing API</button>
    <button onClick={() => { console.log(data.deaths) }}>testing deaths</button>
  </div>
  <div className="bla">
    <Second />
  </div>
</div>
```

)

Comment: worked but can you explain how that happend and also i want to ask is not a solution like this useing async await?

Comment: We are using a short circuit approach here i.e you are conditionally wrapping your JSX. It will only render if your condition is true {condition &&<your JSX />}

Answer (score 0):

There's going to be some delay until you get a response from the API. They're asynchronous, therefore the response will not be immediate.

Since you didn't defined an initial state for `data`, its going to be `undefined` by default. That is why you're getting the error. Basically `<Main />` is trying to render data that is undefined.

The typical approach to circumvent this is to use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND):

```
{ data && JSON.stringify(data) }
```

This checks if `data` is a thing, if it is, then it executes the code to right side (in this case a simply stringification of object).

You can add this safeguard right before you pass down `data` as props:

```
{data && <Main data={data} getValue{getValue} />
```

or directly on the child component. Like I did below:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [drop, setDrop] = React.useState(null);

  const getValue = (e) => {
    setDrop(e.target.value);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let URL;

    if (!drop) {
      URL = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all";
    } else {
      URL = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${drop}?strict=true`;
    }

    fetch(URL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  });

  return (
    <div>
      { /* Pass down data as props */ }
      <Main data={data} getValue={getValue}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const Main = ({ data, getValue }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      { /* If data is a "thing" then map over it */ }
      {data &&
        Object.keys(data).map((k) => (
          <li key={k}>
            {k}: {data[k]}
          </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```